# Take each first element of the group by

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-5.0

How can I take each first element in the group with EF 5 ?

```
      var result = await context.SomeDbSet
          .Where(...)
          .GroupBy(x => new { x.SomeField, ... })
          .Select(x => x.First())
          .ToListAsync();
```

I am getting not supported exception.

How to correctly rewrite query? Thanks.

Comment: Actually there is no way to do that with pure EF, except writhing SQL. Anyway if you ok, I can propose solution via third party extension.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  Thanks for answer. That's all I need to know - just linq without sql is not enough. Anyway, it might be good for somebody to see your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with grouping. SQL has a limitation - with `GROUP BY` you can select only grouping keys and aggregation result. This limitation for sure extended to `LINQ to Entities` - after `GroupBy` you can select only grouping keys and aggregation result.

Such result can be achieved by SQL and Window functions:

```sql
SELECT
  r.*,
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
      s.*, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.SomeField1, s.SomeField2 ORDER BY s.SomeDate) AS RN
   FROM SomeDbSet s
   WHERE ...
) r
WHERE r.RN = 1
```

For those who want to stay with LINQ, I propose extension (disclaimer: I'm extension creator) [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

And you can write query above via LINQ

```cs
var rnQuery = 
   from s in context.SomeDbSet
   where ...
   select new 
   {
      Data = s,
      RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
              .PartitionBy(s.SomeField1, s.SomeField2)
              .OrderBy(s.SomeDate)
              .ToValue()
   }

var resultQuery = await rnQuery
   .Where(r => r.RN == 1)
   .Select(r => r.Data)
   .ToLinqToDB();

var result = resultQuery.ToList();

// async variant may need ToListAsyncLinqToDB() call 
// because of collision in async extension methods between EF Core and linq2db
var result = await resultQuery.ToListAsyncLinqToDB();
```