# net core 5.0 .FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
users = (List<UserResponse>)
        (from u in _context.Users
         join rolePermiss in _context.RolePermissions on u.RoleId equals rolePermiss.RoleId
         group new { u, rolePermiss} by u.Id into gr
         select new UserResponse()
         {
           Id = gr.FirstOrDefault().u.Id,
           //Permissions = gr.FirstOrDefault().rolePermiss.Select(x => x.Id).ToList()
         }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you format your code?

Comment: Just answered the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/66350423/10646316

Comment: Not completely sure but I think I read multiple times that EF can't translate `FirstOrDefault()` inside a grouping. Have you tried using `First()` instead?

Comment: I tried but it still does not work, it worked on ef core 2 version

Answer (score 0):

try this linq

```
users = (List<UserResponse>)
       (from u in _context.Users
        join rolePermiss in _context.RolePermissions on u.RoleId equals rolePermiss.RoleId
        group new { u, rolePermiss } by u.Id into gr
        select gr.FirstOrDefault() into mr
        select new UserResponse()
        {
            Id = mr.u.Id,
            //............
        }).ToList();
```